# Sharepoint - linked web parts?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, webpart

I have a page with 2 web parts.

One of them is a list, where the users can add an item (their personal info).

Once they have entered their personal info, it should show up in the 2nd list (with the option to edit)

So in the end, users should be able to see the info of all the users in the 1st list, but only their own in the 2nd list.

Which approach should I use for this? Should both web parts be lists? On the first list I have a "Created By" column that is automatically set to the user's full name when they enter the info, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Why 2 lists? 1 list, 2 webparts showing that 2 different views of that list. Could even be on different web part pages.

1st web part shows all items, 2nd web part - Filter the view thusly: Created By = [Me]

So, in the second list, all you see are items Created by *you* (or whomever is logged in)